# SQL Server - Sorting by category

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a sorting question. I am using SQL Server 2012. I have the following dataset. The empty lines are for display purposes.

```
Country        CountryUser        State        StateUser
---------------------------------------------------------
Canada         User1              null         null
Canada         User2              null         null
USA            User2              null         null
USA            User3              null         null

Canada         User1              BC           User4
Canada         User1              BC           User5
Canada         User1              ON           User4
Canada         User1              ON           User8

Canada         User2              BC           User4
Canada         User2              BC           User5
Canada         User2              ON           User4
Canada         User2              ON           User8
total rows: 12
```

I want to sort the rows such that all the rows that contain a state are shown below their country(row with null as state). Example,

```
Country        CountryUser        State        StateUser
---------------------------------------------------------
Canada         User1              null         null
Canada         User1              BC           User4
Canada         User1              BC           User5
Canada         User1              ON           User4
Canada         User1              ON           User8

Canada         User2              null         null
Canada         User2              BC           User4
Canada         User2              BC           User5
Canada         User2              ON           User4
Canada         User2              ON           User8

USA            User2              null         null
USA            User3              null         null
total rows: 12
```

The first sort category is Country. The row with an empty state is shown first, then all the states are non null are shown afterwards. These rows have a secondary sort of state

Comment: Order by user, country, state should work...

Answer (score 1):

You can use case in the order by:

```
select * 
from #yourCountry 
order by CountryUser, case when state is null then '00000000' else 'zzzzz' end
                    , case when stateUser is null then '00000000' else 'zzzzz' end
```

Your table:

```
create table #yourCountry ( Country varchar(15), CountryUser varchar(10), State varchar(5), StateUser varchar(10))

insert into #yourCountry (
Country    ,    CountryUser ,       State    ,    StateUser  ) values
---------------------------------------------------------
 ('Canada','User1',null , null )
,('Canada','User2',null , null )
,('USA   ','User2',null , null )
,('USA   ','User3',null , null )
,('Canada','User1','BC','User4')
,('Canada','User1','BC','User5')
,('Canada','User1','ON','User4')
,('Canada','User1','ON','User8')
,('Canada','User2','BC','User4')
,('Canada','User2','BC','User5')
,('Canada','User2','ON','User4')
,('Canada','User2','ON','User8')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an `order by` clause with four columns:

```
select 'Canada'  as Country   ,    'User1' as CountryUser,null as State,null as StateUser
    union all select 'Canada', 'User2', null, null
    union all select 'USA'   , 'User2', null, null
    union all select 'USA'   , 'User3', null, null
    union all select 'Canada', 'User1', 'BC', 'User4'
    union all select 'Canada', 'User1', 'BC', 'User5'
    union all select 'Canada', 'User1', 'ON', 'User4'
    union all select 'Canada', 'User1', 'ON', 'User8'
    union all select 'Canada', 'User2', 'BC', 'User4'
    union all select 'Canada', 'User2', 'BC', 'User5'
    union all select 'Canada', 'User2', 'ON', 'User4'
    union all select 'Canada', 'User2', 'ON', 'User8'
order by Country, CountryUser, State, StateUser
```

these are the results:

[image]

*Edit*:

This works because Sql Server 2012 considers `null` values as the lowest possible. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385(v=sql.110).aspx#Anchor_1) for reference, here is an excerpt:

> ASC | DESC 
>   Specifies that the values in the specified column should be
>   sorted in ascending or descending order. ASC sorts from the lowest
>   value to highest value. DESC sorts from highest value to lowest value.
>   ASC is the default sort order. ***Null values are treated as the lowest
>   possible values.***

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is the reason why it works is order by sorts null values before non nulls?

Comment: @user2769810 Yes it is, I edited my answer adding a brief explanation and a relevant link to MSDN

Answer (score -1):

Select * from table order  by table_atr desc

Comment: sort by country, countryUser, state, stateUser